# LINQ select top 1 grouped and ordered by array indices

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to create a LINQ expression that can:

1. Group by the second index of the nested array ("Dejan", "Branko")
2. Convert the third index to the DateTime and get the max - latest date
3. Based on the 1 and 2 return new array

Here is the input array:

```
var input = [
  [
    "5833d9df-a9bb-49a7-a113-d410801af72a",
    "Dejan",
    "2020-12-03",
    "napraviti program za ovaku TODO listu",
    "RADITI"
  ],
  [
    "5833d9df-a9bb-49a7-a113-d410801af72a",
    "Dejan",
    "2020-12-04",
    "napraviti program za ovaku TODO listu",
    "RADITI"
  ],
  [
    "a9130a6f-d157-4a6e-8b70-430793eddcd3",
    "Branko",
    "2020-12-04",
    "Rekao sam mu da ode kod Voje pa cemo online da resimo sve",
    "CEKAM ODGOVOR"
  ],
  [
    "a9130a6f-d157-4a6e-8b70-430793eddcd3",
    "Branko",
    "2020-12-03",
    "Rekao sam mu da ode kod Voje pa cemo online da resimo sve",
    "CEKAM ODGOVOR"
  ]
];
```

Expected output:

```
var output = [
  [
    "5833d9df-a9bb-49a7-a113-d410801af72a",
    "Dejan",
    "2020-12-04",
    "napraviti program za ovaku TODO listu",
    "RADITI"
  ],
  [
    "a9130a6f-d157-4a6e-8b70-430793eddcd3",
    "Branko",
    "2020-12-04",
    "Rekao sam mu da ode kod Voje pa cemo online da resimo sve",
    "CEKAM ODGOVOR"
  ]
];
```

Here is my attempt to solve the problem (T-SQL):

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E
FROM 
(
  SELECT A, B, C, D, E, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B ORDER BY C DESC) RN
  FROM @TABLE
) A
WHERE A.RN = 1
```

I don't know LINQ

Comment: Hi Dejan, Show us your attempt. Did you face any difficulty or error add that as well. This will help us to answer your question precisely

Comment: Here is the attempt. Can you answer it now?

Comment: Dejan, I think Prasad was asking for an attempt in C# and if you couldn't do it, to tell us where you're stuck.  But regardless, I've provided an answer below.

Comment: When you ask a question here on stackoverflow because you can't solve it yourself, and then you receive the "polite question" and down votes you don't feel good any more. Thank you @pwilcox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GroupBy` and point it to the second entry of each group.  Then, within each group, order by the third entry in descending order and take the first group entry.

```
var output = 
    input
    .GroupBy(entry => entry[1])
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(entry => entry[2]).First());
```

Comment: It is perfect! And it is just as I wrote in 1 and 2. Group by and then take the latest one. Of course, no need for conversion because the date is in such a format. I am building a windows forms application, that will use a simple text file (no db!), work on it with LINQ, and then display it in the webbrowser component. Use text file instead of MSSQL, use forms app to work with files, db, processes etc and use webbrowser component to display UI (HTML, bootstrap, javascript)